# Parseval frame, convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\|g_k\right\|$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $[0, 1)$, and $\{g_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ be a Parseval frame for $L^2(\mu)$. Does
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left\|g_k\right\|$$
converges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any orthonormal basis of $L_2(\mu)$ is a Parseval frame which will cause the series to diverge. So, in general, the answer is no.